# Spark Scala - Cluster / Group a list based on time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have large time series data of several years in this format:

```
eventtime,value
---------------
2013-04-17 11:18:39.0,11.4
2013-04-17 11:19:40.0,82.0
2013-04-17 11:20:41.0,53.8
2013-04-17 17:22:00.0,31.0
2013-04-17 17:23:00.0,22.6
2013-04-17 17:24:00.0,43.1
2013-04-17 21:48:00.0,11.0
2013-04-17 21:49:00.0,22.1
2013-04-17 21:50:00.0,3.2
2013-04-17 21:51:00.0,13.1
```

From the above data, i want to group by clusters of time, and then perform aggregate functions (max, mean) on each group. 
Please note that there are three such clusters in above sample data.
Desired output:

```
Group, Sum
-------------
[2013-04-17 11:18:39.0,2013-04-17 11:19:40.0,2013-04-17 11:20:41.0],147.2
[2013-04-17 17:22:00.0,2013-04-17 17:23:00.0,2013-04-17 17:24:00.0],96.7
[2013-04-17 21:48:00.0,11.0,2013-04-17 21:49:00.0,22.1,2013-04-17 21:50:00.0,2013-04-17 21:51:00.0],49.4
```

These clusters can happen any time of the day, number of the events in a cluster is also not fixed. One way to distinguish these clusters could be by time difference in clusters, say clusters which are one hour apart.

Please suggest me on how to achieve this in Spark Scala.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the above functionality using the below code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat
var doubleFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.00")
val dateFormat = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH")

var groupedRdd = rdd.map(value => value.split(",")).map(arr => (dateFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(arr(0))), (Array(arr(0)), arr(1).toDouble))).cache

// To calculate the sum
var sumRdd = groupedRdd.reduceByKey((obj1 ,obj2 ) => ((obj1._1 ++ obj2._1), (obj1._2 + obj2._2)))
sumRdd.foreach(value => println(value._1 + ":[" + value._2._1.mkString(",") + "]:" + doubleFormat.format(value._2._2)))

// Output of Sum func 
2013-04-17 21:[2013-04-17 21:48:00.0,2013-04-17 21:49:00.0,2013-04-17 21:50:00.0,2013-04-17 21:51:00.0]:49.40
2013-04-17 17:[2013-04-17 17:22:00.0,2013-04-17 17:23:00.0,2013-04-17 17:24:00.0]:96.70
2013-04-17 11:[2013-04-17 11:18:39.0,2013-04-17 11:19:40.0,2013-04-17 11:20:41.0]:147.20


// To calculate Max value
var maxRdd = groupedRdd.reduceByKey((obj1 ,obj2 ) => ((obj1._1 ++ obj2._1), Math.max(obj1._2 , obj2._2)))
maxRdd.foreach(value => println(value._1 + ":[" + value._2._1.mkString(",") + "]:" + doubleFormat.format(value._2._2)))

// Output of Max func
2013-04-17 21:[2013-04-17 21:48:00.0,2013-04-17 21:49:00.0,2013-04-17 21:50:00.0,2013-04-17 21:51:00.0]:22.10
2013-04-17 17:[2013-04-17 17:22:00.0,2013-04-17 17:23:00.0,2013-04-17 17:24:00.0]:43.10
2013-04-17 11:[2013-04-17 11:18:39.0,2013-04-17 11:19:40.0,2013-04-17 11:20:41.0]:82.00


// To calculate the min value
var minRdd = groupedRdd.reduceByKey((obj1 ,obj2 ) => ((obj1._1 ++ obj2._1), Math.min(obj1._2 , obj2._2)))
minRdd.foreach(value => println(value._1 + ":[" + value._2._1.mkString(",") + "]:" + doubleFormat.format(value._2._2)))


// Output of the min value
2013-04-17 21:[2013-04-17 21:48:00.0,2013-04-17 21:49:00.0,2013-04-17 21:50:00.0,2013-04-17 21:51:00.0]:3.20
2013-04-17 17:[2013-04-17 17:22:00.0,2013-04-17 17:23:00.0,2013-04-17 17:24:00.0]:22.60
2013-04-17 11:[2013-04-17 11:18:39.0,2013-04-17 11:19:40.0,2013-04-17 11:20:41.0]:11.40
```

The Output format is : **`cluster:[eventimes]:result`**

Hope above solution will help you in calculating the aggregation results.